# Nested form(cocoon gem) inside a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I'm busy with a invoicing application and i'm trying to put a nested form from the cocoon gem inside a `<tbody></tbody>`. The nested form is working perfectly but it doesn't show up in the `<tbody></tbody>` but at some random place above the table head. I think it's because you can't have `<div class=nested-fields></div>` inside the table body but i'm not sure how to do it differently.

[image]

**i have this in my invoices/_form.html.erb :**

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
<% if @invoice.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@invoice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this invoice from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @invoice.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="hidden-480"> Hoeveelheid </th>
                <th class="hidden-480"> Beschrijving </th>
                <th class="hidden-480"> Bedrag </th>
                <th class="hidden-480"> Totaal </th>
                <th class="hidden-480"> Btw(%) </th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <%= f.fields_for :products do |product| %>
                <%= render 'product_fields', f: product %>
                <%= link_to_add_association 'Item toevoegen', f, :products, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-success' %>
                <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
   <% end %>
```

**invoices/_product_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <tr>
      <td> <%= f.text_field :quantity %> </td>
      <td> <%= f.text_area :description %> </td>
      <td> <%= f.number_field :unitprice %> </td>
      <td> €200  </td>
      <td> <%= f.select(:btw, [[' 21%', 21, title: '21%'],[' 6%', 6, title: '6%'], [' 0%', 0, title: '0%']]) %> </td>
    </tr>
  <%= link_to_remove_association 'x', f, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

**Invoice.rb - model**

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :company
  has_one :customer
  has_many :products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  validates :number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal, :subtotal, :total, presence: true

end
```

**Product.rb - model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :invoice


end
```

**Invoices_controller.rb**

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_invoice, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /invoices
  # GET /invoices.json
  def index
    @invoices = Invoice.all
  end

  # GET /invoices/1
  # GET /invoices/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /invoices/new
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @invoice.products.build
  end

  # GET /invoices/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /invoices
  # POST /invoices.json
  def create
    @invoice = Invoice.new(invoice_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.save
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1
  # PATCH/PUT /invoices/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @invoice.update(invoice_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @invoice, notice: 'Invoice was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @invoice }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @invoice.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /invoices/1
  # DELETE /invoices/1.json
  def destroy
    @invoice.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to invoices_url, notice: 'Invoice was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_invoice
      @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def invoice_params
      params.require(:invoice).permit(:number, :currency, :date, :duedate, :btwtotal,
                                      :subtotal, :total, :footer, customers_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :address_line_1, :zip_code, :_destroy],
                                      companies_attributes: [:id, :btw_number, :iban_number, :kvk_number, :company_name, :_destroy],
                                      products_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :description, :unitprice, :btw, :total])
    end
end
```

**Any idea what's going on? Help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: what is f whose object? Can u show from where f is coming and also the association in model?

Comment: Added everything, thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use built in methods provided by cocoon gem for link_to_add_association,

reference: 
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#link_to_add_association

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Item toevoegen', f, :products,:"data-association-insertion-node" => "tbody#{id of tbody encapsulating your fields_for}",:"data-association-insertion-method" => "append",  class: 'btn btn-primary btn-success' %>
```

P.S this is my first answer in stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Control the Insertion Behaviour section of [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for more reference to insert nested fields.

For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owner a.add_fields").
      data("association-insertion-method", 'append').
      data("association-insertion-traversal", 'closest').
      data("association-insertion-node", '#parent_table');
});
```